# Fetch rows with same id and different prod_id

Tags: sql, union, impala

I have two tables: tbltest1 and tbltest2

I want  all the `distinct` rows of both tables, except the ones that have null in prod_id unless there is not any row in both tables with the same id with a not null prod_id

I tried to make a set with all the values then `DISTINCT`ed to take only the unique ones and after used `ROWNUMBER() OVER()`.:

```
with p as(
select t.*
from tbltest1 as t
union all
select d.*
from tbltest2 as d
),
s as (
select distinct colb, num,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY num ORDER BY colb DESC) as rnk
from p
)select *
from s
where rnk = 1
```

How can I achieve that? Is there also any other more efficient way to do it instead of this logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UNION` for the 2 tables to remove the duplicates (if any) and then `NOT EXISTS`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT prod_id, dn FROM tbltest2
  UNION
  SELECT prod_id1, dn1 FROM tbltest1
)
SELECT c1.*
FROM cte c1
WHERE c1.prod_id IS NOT NULL
   OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cte c2 WHERE c2.dn = c1.dn AND c2.prod_id IS NOT NULL)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4f691795845c6b52f09966046c572077).

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it easy to explain me the logic after the OR NOT EXISTS?

Comment: @Thkas What I understood from your question is that you want all the distinct rows of both tables, except the ones that have `null` in `prod_id` **unless** there is not any row in both tables with the same `id` with a not null `prod_id`. This last part is what NOT EXISTS does.